# How to get Facebook page type

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

Im trying to figure out with the Facebook API how to retrieve the kind of page. For example: if we go to facebook.com/MyOrganisation that it will return a page type organisation. Or if a location it returns a type of location. Any one has a clue?

Answer (score 0):

All possible fields are in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/

Maybe `place_type` is what you want, try with your Page.

Comment: I tried mate but not the result i wanted... I got the categorie, but that has a list with many and then i really mean many, items, not what im looking for. Thanks for the help anyway :)